# Remove images from RichTextBox FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a WPF application on which the user can paste some data from Word inside a RichTextBox... but if that word data has an image, I need to remove it, how can I accomplish that?

Since the FlowDocument is xml, maybe doing some linq magic could do it, but I don't know how.

Comment: There is LogicalTreeUtility used to get specific elements in FlowDocument, may be it can be of use here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/233d3397-0388-473c-8473-721a40cf910c/wpf-customized-find-control-for-flowdocuments.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called WordtoXAML Converter (http://wordtoxaml.codeplex.com). You can use that to convert your Word document contents to XAML, use regular expression matching to identify the images and then strip them out.

Comment: Well, RichTextBox hosting FlowDocument will do the conversion when you paste from Word, so adding 3rd party tool to the solution won't make this task any easier.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want. While it can be a bit wasteful (it looks through the  entire document instead of just the bit that was just pasted), it is the only way to do it, as sometimes the RichTextBox is inaccurate when it indicates the recently painted range:

```
 public class MyTextBox : RichTextBox
    {

        public MyTextBox()
        {
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste, Paste));
        }

        protected virtual void Paste(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Paste();

            foreach (var image in FindImages())
            {
                if (image.SiblingInlines != null)
                {
                    image.SiblingInlines.Remove(image);
                }
            }
        }

        IEnumerable<InlineUIContainer> FindImages()
        {
            var result = new List<InlineUIContainer>();
            var blocks = Document.Blocks;
            for (TextPointer position = blocks.FirstBlock.ElementStart; position != null && position.CompareTo(blocks.LastBlock.ElementEnd) != 1; position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward))
            {
                InlineUIContainer element = position.Parent as InlineUIContainer;
                if (element != null && element.Child is Image)
                {
                    result.Add(element);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```